User journey different types
I would like to know how to proceed with a project for a website relaunch. Do you look at the user journey of a target group as a whole (i.e. from purchase consideration to possible repeat purchase) or really only the path that the user takes on the website?
Don't you first have to understand the general path in order to then look at the exact journey of the user on the website? Is there another name for it?

If this is a relaunch of an existing website, then I assume that there are probably artefacts that capture some aspects of the user journey or analytics of their interaction with the previous website.
I don't know if there are specific or accepted names for these, but I can think of the type of journeys that people might be interested in.

Ideal path, where everything goes smoothly and the user reaches their goal in the shortest amount of steps and/or time
Worst-case scenario, where nothing goes right, and the user experiences many obstacles or delays in attempting to reach their goal
Most common path, where the journey captures the most frequent or typical scenario
Full journey, where every possible combination of paths are documented, which is often a little bit too overwhelming to see all at once (if it even makes sense), so it is often broken up or interactive so you only see sections of the full picture.

Keep in mind that this can then also be multiplied when you have multiple users, multiple use cases and if you are doing a comparison to other similar websites.
I think that covers pretty much all of the user journeys that you might expect to come across.
